# Wifi, connected but not connected

Tags: wi-fi, router

I have a peculiar problem with my Kobo Arc, which runs on Android 4.1.1.
When this device connects to my Dynex router, it goes through the whole "Authenticating" "Obtain IP address" "Connected".  No problem so far on the Wifi screen.

But now when I go online, I get "drops" almost on a pattern, every few seconds the connection will drop (a Youtube video on Youtube app will load, then run 3 sec then never load again until you constantly refresh or reseek, and sometimes that doesn't even work.)

Wifi connection bar remains full and remains "Connected" throughout the entire time, because Router is right next door, and this happens when I'm sitting right in front of it.  I switched Channals from 1-11, I tried different encryption.  To no avail.

So what's the problem here?  It's not signal, and my desktop computer using a USB wifi thingy don't experience this drop.

Comment: Has this device always done this? You might need to contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Un-plug your router for 30 seconds and try again. If it still happens then your router might be going out other than that your device might be buggy and you need to get a new one.